# All combinations of positive and negative values of an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am wondering how to get an array in Ruby with all combinations of positive and negative values based on the values in an input array.  Order does not matter, but must be accommodating to input arrays of all sizes.  It must be flexible so negative numbers could be in the input, even though I didn't include them in the example below.

For example:

input:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

output:

```
b = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,-4],[1,2,-3,-4],[-1,2,-3,-4]...[1,-2,3,-4],[1,-2,-3,-4],[-1,-2,-3,-4],[-1,-2,-3,4],[-1,-2,3,4],[-1,2,3,4]]
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: How about -1,2,-3,4? Do you also want these, or positive and negative have to be in orders?

Comment: ahh yes, good point.  i think i need to go to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way (a variant of @JoshuaCheek's answer):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

n = a.size
(2**n).times.map { |i|
  ("%0#{n}b" % i).split('').zip(a).map { |b,e| (b=='1') ? e : -e } }
  #=> [[-1, -2, -3, -4], [-1, -2, -3, 4], [-1, -2, 3, -4], [-1, -2, 3, 4],
  #    [-1,  2, -3, -4], [-1,  2, -3, 4], [-1,  2, 3, -4], [-1,  2, 3, 4],
  #    [ 1, -2, -3, -4], [ 1, -2, -3, 4], [ 1, -2, 3, -4], [ 1, -2, 3, 4],
  #    [ 1,  2, -3, -4], [ 1,  2, -3, 4], [ 1,  2, 3, -4], [ 1,  2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: This works great too.  I like how the output is an array without having to build the output array by iterating through the loop.  Great solution!  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You'll notice, as you iterate through the positives and negatives, that the pattern with which you apply the negativity is the same as the pattern you would use to increment bits as you count in binary. This is because each index in the array can have one of two values (positive or negative), just like each bit in a binary number can have one of two values (0 or 1). So, the easy solution is to map 0 and 1 to positive and negative. Then we can just do normal Ruby iterating, and check the bit at the element's corresponding index.

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  # => [1, 2, 3, 4]

signed = [a, a.map(&:-@)]                            # => [[1, 2, 3, 4], [-1, -2, -3, -4]]
(0...2**a.size).each do |n|                          # => 0...16
  p Array.new(a.size) { |i| signed[n[i]][i] }  # => [1, 2, 3, 4], [-1, 2, 3, 4], [1, -2, 3, 4], [-1, -2, 3, 4], [1, 2, -3, 4], [-1, 2, -3, 4], [1, -2, -3, 4], [-1, -2, -3, 4], [1, 2, 3, -4], [-1, 2, 3, -4], [1, -2, 3, -4], [-1, -2, 3, -4], [1, 2, -3, -4], [-1, 2, -3, -4], [1, -2, -3, -4], [-1, -2, -3, -4]
end                                                  # => 0...16

# >> [1, 2, 3, 4]
# >> [-1, 2, 3, 4]
# >> [1, -2, 3, 4]
# >> [-1, -2, 3, 4]
# >> [1, 2, -3, 4]
# >> [-1, 2, -3, 4]
# >> [1, -2, -3, 4]
# >> [-1, -2, -3, 4]
# >> [1, 2, 3, -4]
# >> [-1, 2, 3, -4]
# >> [1, -2, 3, -4]
# >> [-1, -2, 3, -4]
# >> [1, 2, -3, -4]
# >> [-1, 2, -3, -4]
# >> [1, -2, -3, -4]
# >> [-1, -2, -3, -4]
```

Answer (score 2):

While other answers already dabbled in the `Array` methods, `Array#repeated_permutation` is what is really needed here:

```
[ 1, -1 ].repeated_permutation( 4 ).map { |p| [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ].zip( p ).map { |u, v| u * v } }
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ruby conveniently includes a `combination` method on the `Array` object, but first you need to create the opposite values for the numbers in the original array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a.map(&:-@)
```

Then you'd want to concatenate the two arrays into a single array:

```
c = a + b
```

And finally you can call the `combination` method of the array that contains all the positive and negative values:

```
c.combination(4).to_a # => [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,-1], ...]
```

Here is the documentation for the [combination method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-combination).

**Update:** I like what Boris Stitnicky came up with. Here's a variation on that:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]

def sign_permutations(arr)
  [1, -1].repeated_permutation(arr.length).map do |signs|
    signs.map.with_index do |sign, index|
      arr[index] * sign
    end
  end
end

puts sign_permutations(a).inspect
```

Comment: This is a superset of what the OP is asking

Comment: Yeah, I can't have a repeated number either.  So [1,2,3,-1] wouldn't cut it.  I just need all the combinations of positives and negatives of each number in the array.  Sorry, its hard to describe this. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @jfrench009 Yeah, then that technically wouldn't be a combination. That's what threw me off.

Answer (score 0):

```
array=[]
[1,-1].each do |a|
    [2,-2].each do |b|
        [3,-3].each do |c|
             [4,-4].each do |d|
                  array<<[a,b,c,d]
              end
          end
     end
end
```

I'll elaborate on a more complete amswer as soon as I get my hands on a keyboard

**Update**:
A lot of good answer, here is the recursive way:

```
@input = [1,2,3,4] # or whatever
@output = []
def pos_neg(ind,in_array)
    a=@input[ind]
    [a,-a].each do |b|
        arr=in_array.dup
        arr[ind]=b
        if @input.size > ind+1
            pos_neg(ind+1,arr)
        else
            @output << arr
        end
    end
end
```

Then, you run:

```
pos_neg(0,[])
@output
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
[1, 2, 3, -4],
[1, 2, -3, 4],
[1, 2, -3, -4],
[1, -2, 3, 4],
[1, -2, 3, -4],
[1, -2, -3, 4],
[1, -2, -3, -4],
[-1, 2, 3, 4],
[-1, 2, 3, -4],
[-1, 2, -3, 4],
[-1, 2, -3, -4],
[-1, -2, 3, 4],
[-1, -2, 3, -4],
[-1, -2, -3, 4],
[-1, -2, -3, -4]]
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for, but now I need it to be more flexible so I can have 10 or 20 numbers in the input array.

Answer (score 0):

The below approach works - basically, we use a bit mask between binary 0000 to 1111 (or decimal 0 to 15) to decide which numbers should be negative (0 is positive, 1 is negative) - more details in the comments in the code below :

```
require 'pp'
result = []
# consider binary number mask from binary 0000 to 1111, 
# where each digit if 0 uses the positive number, and if 1 uses the negative number
(0..15).each do |mask|
  combin = [] # each combination
  # Next, loop through the four place values (1,2,4,8)
  (0..3).each do |pwr|
    pv = 2 ** pwr # each place value
    if ((mask & pv) == pv) # if the mask has the bit set at this place value, 
      combin << -(pwr + 1) # use the negative of the number (pwr + 1 gives 1, 2, 3, 4 nicely)
    else # if mask doesn't have the bit set at this place value
      combin << (pwr + 1) # use the positive value of the number
    end
  end  
  result << combin 
end
pp result

# Output:  
# [[1, 2, 3, 4],
#  [-1, 2, 3, 4],
#  [1, -2, 3, 4],
#  [-1, -2, 3, 4],
#  [1, 2, -3, 4],
#  [-1, 2, -3, 4],
#  [1, -2, -3, 4],
#  [-1, -2, -3, 4],
#  [1, 2, 3, -4],
#  [-1, 2, 3, -4],
#  [1, -2, 3, -4],
#  [-1, -2, 3, -4],
#  [1, 2, -3, -4],
#  [-1, 2, -3, -4],
#  [1, -2, -3, -4],
#  [-1, -2, -3, -4]]
```